# How are close votes tallied when different reasons for closure are given?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I recently noticed a question that had been voted to close by three different people. Two votes were cast as "primarily opinion-based" and the third was cast as "too broad."

I was just wondering how this works in terms of the five vote closure threshold. Does a question have to reach five closure votes for a single, specific reason; or do any five closure votes reach the threshold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe any five closure votes reach the threshold, and the reason that's shown is the most popular one. If a moderator casts a close vote, the question will be immediately closed (regardless of vote counts) and the close reason the moderator uses is what will be shown.